# Appending a dictionary to a dictionary

Tags: python

I opened csv file as dictionary and try to append it to existing dictionary row by row. But it seems like it's not appending. rather, the existing dictionary only holding current row in a loop. So, what am I doing wrong?

```py
buffer = {}
with open("small.csv", "r") as input:
  reader = csv.DictReader(input)
    for row in reader:
      buffer |= row
      print(buffer)
```

Buffer dictionary is supposed to store all rows in reader, but it's only holding current row. I tried to use `buffer.update(row)` but found same result.

Comment: Also, why are you using `|=`?

Comment: Every dict you get from the `DictReader` is going to have the same set of keys - so you're just overwriting previous values on every iteration after the first.

Comment: What do you mean "store all rows"? Is it supposed to map a column to a list of values for that column?

Comment: Please provide an example csv file and what you expect buffer dict to be

Comment: I already figured it out. thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

You can't add "rows" to a dictionary. What you need is a `list`, i.e:

```
buffer = []
```

then

```
...
for row in reader:
    buffer.append(row)
...
```

In the end your `buffer` will be a list of dicts, where each dict is a separate row.